How does counting in classical 32-bit systems compare to quantum systems with 32 qubits in superposition?
I'm trying to understand how counting in a classical 32-bit system compares to a 32-qubit quantum system.
In a classical 32-bit system, we can count from 0 to the maximum value (i.e., ) using a CPU clock. The time required is determined by the clock speed. For example, at a clock speed of 1 GHz, counting would take roughly 8.589 seconds for the full cycle (from 0 to max of 32-bit and back to 0).
However, we don't need binary counting that works sequentially since it's time dependend. In a 32-qubit quantum system where all qubits are initialized in a superposition state, theoretically, you would get a uniform probability distribution over all possible 32-bit values. In experiments on quantum computers, the "clock" can be analogized to the number of shots needed (e.g., 8192 shots).
But here's where I'm confused: 8192 shots is significantly smaller than the maximum possible value of 32-bit numbers ( = 4,294,967,296). How does the probability distribution of the quantum system get "drawn" or sampled if we use fewer shots than the total number of possible states?
Does this mean that quantum computing does indeed happen simultaneously in the quantum world, but since we live in a classical world, we need to perform MANY multiple shots (similar to how a CPU or binary counter works) to get the full distribution over time?
How is this process of "sampling" from superposition in quantum computers different from or analogous to counting with a classical clock, considering the number of shots vs. the number of classical cycles?

You should clarify what you are comparing. If you just want to count to $2^{32}$, you don't need a quantum computer. On the other hand, if you want to sample from the balanced distribution including all computational basis states on 32 qubits, I would not call it counting but rather sampling. The aim in quantum computing is measuring an observable to a certain precision, so you might want to specify that. If you want a tomography of the state, you will always need exponentially many measurements.


Does this mean that quantum computing does indeed happen simultaneously in >the quantum world, but since we live in a classical world, we need to perform >MANY multiple shots (similar to how a CPU or binary counter works) to get the >full distribution over time?

In quantum computing, the quantum world does indeed operate simultaneously, using quantum superposition. However, because we live in a classical world, we need to perform many measurements (shots) to obtain a reliable distribution of outcomes over time.
Many important quantum algorithms, such as Grover's search algorithm, begin with a uniform superposition state. They then apply a series of unitary transformations that amplify the amplitude of the desired state. As a result, the probability of measuring the desired state increases and becomes close to 1, reducing the need for extensive sampling.

Interval between two shots still requires time, what is the different between clock period in classical computing then?
